# SQL query to make a 'Find' function in a database (in Yii framework)

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

Given a string of text as search criteria, in every field in a (very large, 50+ columns) table.

there is one main table and many smaller ones that are connected to it, but have 'ids' in the main table, not actual searchable text values.

such as:

```
TABLE SALES LOCATIONS
id location_name customer_id ... other fields
2  normalville   4
```

where customer id is the primary key in another table:

```
TABLE CUSTOMER
id name industry
4  EXC  Selling Things
```

is there any elegant way to accomplish this with SQL without using a whole slew of joins or subqueries specifically targeted at each of the 50+ fields?

there are probably 11 fields in the main table that are actually just ids pointing to other tables.

also of note, I am using the Yii framework.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it will be impossible to do this without joining the other tables.

Comment: You could do a Magento-style hack and create a *flat* search table holding a copy of all the data in the relevant columns then stick a `FULLTEXT` index across the lot - good luck with maintaining synchronicity though. Or, using your current structure, you might find you get better performance by having the correct indexes on each table and querying them individually ... often lots of little queries run faster than one, big complicated one.

Comment: @CD001 just to clarify, use subqueries for all of the info outside the main table work? it'd be extra effort but I think it'd make the performance of the database better? like I'm thinking something like

SELECT * FROM `table1` where `column1`=(SELECT `id` FROM `table2` WHERE `name` LIKE %searchterm%)

repeated over and over for each column that has to reach into another table.

Comment: It probably won't work exactly like that - that subquery will probably return multiple records so it's likely to fail... unless you're doing something like `WHERE t1.column1 IN (SELECT ... )` - but if the sub-queries are simple and the `name` column being searched on is properly indexed, it should perform pretty well.